# Need help on C programming -> pointer

Tags: c++

1. What is the error here?

   ```
   int main() {
       int* pointer = new int [1000];

       if (!pointer) return -1;

       for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
           *pointer++ = j;

       If (pointer) {
           delete [] pointer;
           pointer = NULL;
               }

       return 0;
   }
   ```

Comment: `pointer` no longer holds the original value it received upon the return of `new int[1000]`. The statement `*pointer++ = j;` increments it down the sequence with each iteration. Therefore, `delete [] pointer` invokes *undefined behavior*. Use a different pointer for the enumeration. Finally, **stop spamming tags**. This post has absolutely *nothing* to do with C#, nor C. If this were C, the very first problem would be neither `new` or `delete` are constructs that language understands.

Comment: `new [ ]` returned a value back to you.  You must use the very same value when you issue the `delete [ ]` call.  Obviously you are not doing that.

Answer (score 0):

In the statement

```
*pointer++ = j;
```

the `pointer` is moved to next location in the allocated memory. *[The post increment operator increase the value of operand by `1` but the value of the expression is the operand's original value prior to the increment operation]*

After `for` loop the `pointer` is pointing to memory one past the allocated array memory and here

```
delete [] pointer;
```

your program is trying to `delete` a memory which it doesn't own.

To fix this, while inserting the elements in the array take a temporary pointer

```
int* temp = pointer;
for (int j = 0; j < 1000; j++)
    *temp++ = j;
```